# Laravel valet using wrong version of PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I'm running valet 2.0.5 and it is using the wrong version of PHP. When starting valet I get

```
$ valet start
Restarting php71...
Restarting nginx...
Valet services have been started.
```

But `phpinfo()` gives `PHP Version 5.6.30` and `Loaded Configuration File:  /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini`.

I've installed and relinked php using brew,

```
$ which php
/usr/local/opt/php71/bin/php

$ php -v
PHP 7.1.7
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling valet, to no avail.

Comment: Did you try?

 brew unlink php56

Comment: @Jed `$ brew unlink php56: Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php56`. I believe for whatever reason my valet is using my macOS php...

Comment: Huh, I ran into this once before.  I gave up on brew and used the CURL method described here.  https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-upgrade-your-version-of-php-to-7-0-on-macos-sierra-e1bfdea55a63

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncommenting `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` did the trick. I don't really know why this worked, but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 11):

The old version of PHP (in my case 7.4) was "stuck" for some reason in Valet. Even though `php -v` returns me php 8.0. The way to force Valet to choose the right version you can use the following command:

```
valet use php@8.0 --force
```

Comment: getting error: The "--force" option does not exist.

Comment: This did the trick after much investigation

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem when upgrading from 7.1 to 7.2.

For me the solution was that I removed the symlinks for php7.1 from /usr/local/opt/